# QGIS 3.10 Page settings won't accept changes of page size A3

Tags: qgis, print-composer

What can I do to change the page layout to A3 under QGIS FreeBSD 12 . The settings for layout_page_width/ layout_page_height are not enabled for editing, and page settings to A3 for from the printer dialog are not adopted.

Comment: You right-click the page - Properties but the settings are greyed out?

Comment: OK that seems to works, but not in the layout settings of the property sheet.

Comment: The only way to change the sheet size in the QGIS print composer is to right click the sheet and enter the page settings there. It's a bit annoying/hard to find.

Comment: Hm... page settings under 3.10 are really annoying. If you change your layout size over the menu nothing is stored at the layout level, editing is possible but complicated thanks

Comment: @huckfinn I agree with you. The current "r-click on the page" process is confusing and counter-intuitive!

Answer (score 0):

The right click option works when you first create a new layout, but it doesn't seem to work if you're trying to edit an existing layout. Right-clicking on an existing layout only gives grayed-out menu choices of undo and redo. When you open up a new layout, before adding any information to the layout, you can right-click and see the Page Properties option, along with a functional "Manage Guides for Page" option. It also provides the grayed-out menu choices of undo and redo, as well as a grayed-out "Remove Page" option.